# aws glue cloudformation parquet job

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

Anyone have a sample yaml Cloudformation template for a glue job that does JSON to Parquet format conversion? The documentation surrounding Glue Jobs in Cloudformation is a little weak and having a starting point would help a lot. I have written part of the template but finding correctly establishing some of the fields is proving a little confusing.

Specifically, I am having difficulty finding out how to appoint a temporary directory for the job's execution as well as appointing source and destination locations in S3.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you asking for the glue job code or cloudformation code, your questions isn't clear and they are two different things. The gluejob cloudformation sets up the resource, the gluejob code is what does the conversion

Comment: My trick in cloudformation scenarios is, if you cannot find a sample template, describe an existing object that you created via the console. In this case a job:

`aws glue get-job --job-name some-glue-job`

Answer (score 0):

for Yaml part of CloudFormation and temporary directory in s3 you can use this

```
Type: AWS::Glue::Job
Properties:
  DefaultArguments:
    '--TempDir': 's3://bucket-name/directory'
```

part of " appointing source and destination locations in S3" i don't undestand scenario for this... Can you give me more info?